# Realm.deleteRealmFile() deprecated android?

Tags: android, file, migration, realm

Now that **Realm.deleteRealmFile()** is deprecated, what is the best way to remove the realm file and instantiate a new one in an android application?

I have tried setting a new configuration, though I am getting a **bunch of Realm Migration** errors? Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Per the API documentation, you should now use `DeleteRealm(RealmConfiguration)` instead, where `RealmConfiguration` specifies, among other things, the Realm file to be deleted. You can find the API documentation here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/

Comment: Also remember to set the schemaVersion in your ReamConfiguration. If the version doesn't match the version in your Realm file you will also get a migration error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck in MigrationNeededException loop, try this, it will delete the whole folder and rebuild the Realm.

```
 private void rebuildDatabase() {
        RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .name(getString(R.string.realm_file_name))
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);
        File dir = realmConfig.getRealmFolder();
        if (dir.isDirectory())
        {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
            {
                new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
            }
        }
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
        Realm newRealm = Realm.getInstance(this);
        newRealm.close();
    }
```